# populate list of option when a checkbox is selected using javascript

Tags: javascript

Need to populate a list of options with checkbox when a checkbox is clicked. let consider there are three checkbox when a checkbox is selected beneath that checkbox a list of options with checkbox should appear. if a checkbox is selected then beneath that and so on........

how to do this in javascript.....any help..........

Comment: Please ask a detailed question, with the question you have asked it is not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: i want display an form with three checkbox vertically. when a checkbox is selected it should again list checkbox beneath that checkbox. if any other checkbox in that list is checked then again three checkbox should appear beneath that and so on.......

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are static, I would define them ahead of time in divs, and set the visibility to false.  Then, in your OnClick methods of the checkboxes, simply set the visibility to true when necessary.

Comment: I agree, but might want to use the display property instead. Visibility will still take up space even when hidden.

Comment: Good point @AllisonC; might be better off using style:display.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked a very generic question, I'll give a very generic answer.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NFs4K/3/

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    template = '<li>\
        <input type="checkbox">\
    </li>\
    <li>\
        <input type="checkbox">\
    </li>\
    <li>\
        <input type="checkbox">\
    </li>';


container.onchange = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event,
        target = event.srcElement || event.target;

    if( target.checked && target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul').length === 0 ) {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.innerHTML = template;
        target.parentNode.appendChild(ul);
    } else {
        var ul = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        target.parentNode.removeChild(ul);
    }
};
```

If you want a better answer, please ask a more detailed question.

---

**EDIT:** Removed the `checkboxes` variable. It wasn't being used.

---

**EDIT:** I updated so that it only appends the sub-list when checked, and only the *first* time it is checked.

---

**EDIT:** Updated to remove all nested levels when unchecked.

Comment: i want display an form with three checkbox vertically. when a checkbox is selected it should again list checkbox beneath that checkbox. if any other checkbox in that list is checked then again three checkbox should appear beneath that and so on.......

Comment: one problem in that. even if checkbox is unchecked three checkbox appear. it should be changed like if checkbox is unchecked then the three checkbox below that must be removed........

Comment: @mtw: I just updated. Now it will only add the sub-list when checked, and only the first time it is checked.

Comment: thanks for that .. but when the checkbox is unchecked the checkbox created beneath that  must be removed .. can u help me in that.........

Comment: @mtw: Yes, I'll help you, but these are the details you should include in your question. Let me ask, if you *uncheck* a box that has several levels below it, then when you check that same box again, should *all* those nested levels be restored, or should it start over by just adding one nested level?

Comment: when checked i should add only one nested level beneath that. but when unchecked it must remove all the nested level beneath it..

Comment: and also each checkbox should have unique id........... so that, it must be easy to refer any checkbox in any level...........

Comment: @mtw: I updated the answer. Now it removes all nested levels when unchecked. And when it is checked again, it adds one level with 3 boxes.

Comment: ya thanks.. can we assign unique id to each checkbox to refer or there is any way to refer any checkbox in any level......

Comment: @mtw: That is beyond the scope of your original question. Please do the proper research and try to find a way to do it. If you get stuck on something specific, post another question.

Comment: how to add onclick event to newly createdelement. eg . d=document.createElement("textbox"); how to add onclick event to d?????

Comment: `d.onclick = function() { alert('clicked'); };` and if you were hoping to create a text input, then you'd need `var d=document.createElement("input"); d.addAttribute('type','text');`